# Repeating Section Content Control from Power Automate Works Properly in Word Online but not Word Desktop

Tags: outlook, ms-word, power-automate

This is a very specfic issue that I don't know if anyone else has encountered. I belive this is fundamentally a problem with Word and not Power Automate, but I want to include all of my steps for completion's sake.

In short the issue is that I have a Word Document that I need to be dynamically created based on input from a user, which then gets emailed to said user. I am using Power Automate to dynamically populate word templates and email them to the end user. This works great for my standard plain text content controls, and for repeating section content controls as well. When I get the file in my Outlook Online email and preview it, I see all the content as expected. However, when I then download and open the file, the content in the repeating contetn control is duplicated instead of showing up properly.

Since the real data I'm using is confidential, I have recreated a very simple case for illustration. Here is my word document with my repeating section content control:

[Word Document in Design Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rOQy.png)

I then have a very simple Power Automate flow that populates this file, with its output shown below:

[Power Automate Output Pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiBH2.png)
[Power Automate Output Pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFpzz.png)

When I then recieve the email in my outlook and preview it, it looks like this, which is the expected and desired result:

[Output Online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy2xe.png)

However, when I then download the file and open it in Word, it looks like this:

[Output on Word Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcBIr.png)

No matter what I try, the Repeating Section Content Control will simply repeat the first bit of content entered. This behavior is the same for as many repeating sections as I have tried. Even more interestingly, when I first open the Word Doc and it is in Read-Only mode, all of the Repeating sections except for the first one are blank. Only after enabling editing do they all revert to the same thing.

There is very little information out there on how the frankly outdated Word developer tools interface with newer mechanics of Word such as Word Online. I would appreciate any insight on how to resolve this issue, as the client this project is for exclusivly uses the Desktop Version of Word.

I am also open to non Power Automate methods to solve the problem. (In the proper implementation of this and not the example here, the data is fed in via an API call to the Power Automate Script from a PHP web app, so any solutions using PHP would be extra helpful). I also know that Microsoft Word is not the ideal text editor in Automation use cases, but the Client has all of their templates in Word and is used to them. A non-word solution could be possible however, so I am also open to ideas of other ways to dynamically fill out formatted rich text content. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access Power Automate, but I wonder if the Desktop versions of Word might be a bit more demanding about the XML mappings it is using. Can you please provide the XML Custom Part XML and the two XML mappings to that part in your sample document? You should be able to unzip the .docx and find them. The XML part might contain something along the lines of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:data xmlns:t='testns'>
  <t:repeating_control>
    <t:paragrpah>false</t:paragrpah>
  </t:repeating_control>
</t:data> , ...

Comment: and given that XML, the mapping for the repeating control might look something like /ns0:data[1]/ns0:repeating_control, and the mapping for the "paragrpah" control  would be something like /ns0:data[1]/ns0:repeating_control[1]/ns0:paragrpah[1] for the first pargraph, /ns0:data[1]/ns0:repeating_control[1]/ns0:paragrpah[2] for the second, and so on.